# Frege and Value-Range

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, frege

I have been reading [Kevin C. Klement's article](http://www.iep.utm.edu/frege/#H4) on Gottlob Frege in the Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy. I am confused by the term "value-range", which is used numerous times throughout the article. Here is what is said about it:

> "value-ranges" (Werthverläufe) of functions, understood as objects corresponding to the complete argument-value mappings generated by functions.

I could use some help parsing this concept.

Comment: At the time of Frege's writing logicians did not yet clearly distinguish between extension, set of pre-defined objects falling under a concept, and intensional class of objects, possibly not yet known or defined, that might conceivably fall under the concept at some point. Frege's "value-ranges" were a conflation of the two, which is why he got in trouble with his Basic Law V. "Value-range of a concept not included in itself" is ambiguous as to its extension (the value-range itself is not pre-defined as an object), if it is treated as a set it leads to Russell's paradox.

Comment: @Conifold can one create an axiom to restrict "the set that does not include itself" as a predicate and be free of the paradox?

Comment: @Nick That's what Zermelo did by restricting comprehension to predefined sets, it is the specification axiom schema of ZF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider a numerical function, defined by:

> **f(1)=2, f(2)=4,** ...

The *Wertverlauf* is the "graph" of the function, i.e. the collection of couples:

> **(1,2), (2,4),**...

For *concepts*, i.e. functions from objects to truth-values, like e.g. *Philosopher*, where we have:

> **Phil(Plato)=True** and **Phil(Napoleon)=False**, etc.

we have similarly for the *Wertverlauf*:

> **(Plato,True), (Napoleon, False)**, ...

Thus, strictly speaking, the *Wertverlauf* of a concept is not (but quite similar to) its *extension*: the collection of objects that *fall under* the concept (i.e. that satisfy it). [See [Frege](http://www.iep.utm.edu/frege/#H4): "In the case of concepts, their value-ranges were identified with their extensions."]

---

See [Function and Concept](http://fitelson.org/proseminar/frege_fac.pdf) (1891): "Wertverlauf" has been translated as "value-range" and as "course-of-values".

Comment: Can a value range be placed in equality to a letter, $A = \vec e (e = e)$, such that $\vdash A(0), ..., \vdash A(n)$ holds?